# How to set a max size for divs that contain large images?

Tags: html, css

I have a div.container that has some div.card s inside it. Each div.card has a image that's really big so I want to limit the height of the div.card s. So

I made div.container to be a grid container with grid-auto-rows: minmax(auto, 200px). The div.card resizes but the images overflow, even though they have height 100% set.

Minimized code that causes problems:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3f/Fronalpstock_big.jpg/1200px-Fronalpstock_big.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3f/Fronalpstock_big.jpg/1200px-Fronalpstock_big.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(auto, 200px);
}

div.card {
    display: grid;
}

div.card > img {
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/Bino-Manjesh/pen/dyarWdK

Also, it works as intended in firefox but not on chromium. On chromium it works if I remove display: grid from the div.card. (I need display grid because there is going to be some text along with the img in div.card)

Is this possibly a bug?

Edit:

Result on Chromium
[image: Result on chromium]

Result on Firefox (Intended Result)
[image]

Comment: `max-height: 100%;` <-- [This does not do what you think it does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height#formal_definition): "_The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. **If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly** (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, **the percentage value is treated as `none`**._"

Comment: But if I add `height: 200px` to `div.card`, the image still overflows

Answer (score 0):

If you want a full-width image, with no overflow or stretching, you can use `object-fit:cover` to have the browser fit the image for you.

```
div.card > img {
    max-height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: What I wanted is that the image should scale down such that the height of the `div.card` doesn't get too big

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can try using `object-fit: cover` to adjust with your parent div size and `overflow: hidden` to hide the unnecessary portion of image displayed. Secondly, try running your codes on private/incognito. Most similar cases happen because your browser's caching.

Comment: What I wanted is that the image should scale down such that the height of the div.card doesn't get too big. Also I tried it in icognito and after disabling caching. It still behaves as expected in firefox but not on chromium